# Reimplementing Array.prototype.sort and understanding the return 0;

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, prototype

I'm trying to reimplement the sort algorithm. But to do that first I have to reimplement the compareFunction default. But I don't understand the return 0 behavior described on the documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements.

I am trying to reimplement the same behavior using the bubble algorithm:
http://khan4019.github.io/front-end-Interview-Questions/sort.html#bubbleSort

Comment: When the compare function finds no difference between two values, it is supposed to return `0`.  The underlying sort algorithm is supposed to preserve the relative order of the two when the sort callback returns `0`, but will obviously sort them both relative to all the other elements that do not compare the same.  Preserving the relative order doesn't matter when the values are primitives since you can't tell which primitive is which, but it can make a difference for objects which make have an identical sort key, but not identical other properties.

Comment: Following @jfriend00 answer, you can check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905038/order-sort-text-and-numbers-works-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-not-safari/38905402#38905402 It shows the differences in the `sort` implementation between browsers.

Comment: Returning 0 just means that they are considered equal.

Comment: @jfriend00 Any ideas of how to implement it with the bubbleSort algorithm?